# SortedList does not name a type

Tags: c++, linked-list

Code provided by professor and must be implemented using the following header file:

```
#ifndef SET_LIST_H_
#define SET_LIST_H_

#include "List.h"
#include "SortedList.h"
#include "ListNode.h"

class SetList
{
private:
    SortedList *sortedList;

public:
    SetList();
    void addValue(int);
    bool containsValue(int);
    bool isEmpty();
    void print();
    void removeValue(int);
    virtual ~SetList();
};
#endif
```

Error: SortedList does not name a type.

Also, in my .cpp file, sortedList can't be accessed by any of the public members of the class, receiving the error that sortedList is not defined in the scope.

SortedList.h, also provided by prof:

```
#ifndef SORTED_LIST_H_
#define SORTED_LIST_H_

#include "List.h"
#include "SetList.h"
#include "ListNode.h"

class SortedList: public List
{
public:
    SortedList();
    void appendValue(int);
    void insertValue(int);
    virtual ~SortedList();
};
#endif
```

List.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include "ListNode.h"

using namespace std;



class List
{
private:
     ListNode *listHead = nullptr;

protected:
    ListNode *getListHead();
    void setListHead (ListNode *);

public:

    //constructor
    List();
    virtual ~List();
    virtual void appendValue(int);
    bool containsValue(int);
    virtual void insertValue(int);
    bool isEmpty();
    void removeValue(int);
    void print();
};
#endif
```

ListNode.h:

```
#ifndef _LISTNODE_H_
#define _LISTNODE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

class ListNode
{
private:
        ListNode *next = nullptr;
        int nodeValue = 0;


public:
    ListNode(int);
    ListNode *getNext();
    void setNext(ListNode*);
    int getValue();
    void putValue(int);
    virtual ~ListNode();
};
#endif
```

**List.h, ListNode.h were part of a prior assignment, we are now extending the List class using set and sorted list classes**

Comment: check recent edit @songyuanyao

Comment: The circular `#include`s aren't going to help.  Please post the contents of List.h and ListNode.h too.

Comment: It's a circular dependency issue. `SetList.h` (and `ListNode.h`) should not be included in `SortedList.h`. Only includes necessary header files.

Comment: Sorted list.h should not include SetList.h

Comment: I fixed the header file issues, still receiving the original errors :(